# Is IN syntactic sugar from = ANY?

Tags: sql

1) As far as I understand the comparison = ANY looks quite similar to IN. Is it so? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM HOUSES 
WHERE TYPE = ANY (SELECT TYPE FROM TYPES WHERE CAT_ID = 'PUBLIC')
```

Is it always equal to say?

```
SELECT * FROM HOUSES 
WHERE TYPE IN (SELECT TYPE FROM TYPES WHERE CAT_ID = 'PUBLIC')
```

2) What about NOT IN? Is it equal to <> ALL? I tend to think it is, but can't see it clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about `IN` being equivalent to `= ANY`. On this subject, the SQL:2016 standard (ISO 9075-2:2016) says:

> ### 8.4 <in predicate>
>
> [..]
>
> #### Syntax Rules
>
> [..]
>
> 4) The expression
>
> ```
> RVC NOT IN IPV
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> NOT ( RVC IN IPV )
> ```
>
> 5) The expression
>
> ```
> RVC IN IPV
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> RVC = ANY IPV
> ```

The equivalence of `IN` is in point 5, and point 4 somewhat answers your question about `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your database supports the `ANY` operator (some other databases do not support it).  Using `ANY` with `=` followed by a subquery is logically equivalent to using `IN` followed by the same subquery.  But the difference is that `ANY` also supports the other comparison operators `>`, `>=`, `<`, and `<=`.

The comparison `<> ALL` is saying that every record in the subquery is *not* equal to the value on the LHS.  The negation of this is that there exists one or more records in the subquery which does equal the LHS.  So, the opposite of `<> ALL` is just `IN`.

Comment: Could be SQL Server too: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-any/

Comment: Quantified comparison predicates (eg `= ANY`) are defined in the SQL standard. It is also supported by Firebird, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, HSQLDB and likely many others I haven't looked at.

Comment: Most databases support `ANY`/`SOME`/`ALL`.  They are part of standard SQL and have been for close to forever.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, `= ANY` is always equal to `IN`.

   **ANY** uses `OR` on the values

   `chosen = ANY('True', 'Yes')`

   when expanded:

   `chosen = 'True' OR chosen = 'Yes'`

   is same as:

   `chosen IN ('True', 'Yes')`

   when expanded:

   `chosen = 'True' OR chosen = 'Yes'`

   `ANY`/`IN` both uses **OR**
2. Yes, `NOT IN` is always equal to `<> ALL`.

   **ALL** uses `AND` on the values

   `chosen <> ALL ('Yes', 'True')`

   when expanded:

   `chosen <> 'Yes' AND chosen <> 'True'`

   is same as:

   `chosen NOT IN ('Yes', 'True')`

   is same as:

   `NOT (chosen IN ('Yes', 'True'))`

   when expanded:

   `NOT (chosen = 'Yes' OR chosen = 'True')`

   Applying De Morgan Theorem:

   `chosen <> 'Yes' AND chosen <> 'True'`

   `<> ALL`/`NOT IN` both uses **AND**

I tried to google if there's a stackoverflow answer that can make the explanation "click" for me.

Found the [answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-%E2%80%98any%E2%80%99-%E2%80%98all%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98exists%E2%80%99-in-SQL) on quora.

*Notice, pseudo-code ahead. The query will not work out of the box. To make the query actually work, encapsulate the list to what an "Any"/"All" can operate on, e.g., an [array](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc56c6/3)*, [values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cc56c6/12)

“Any” : It is equivalent to **“OR”** condition. Hence in below example when salary > 2000 or 3000 or 4000 is considered

```
SELECT empno, sal
FROM   emp
WHERE  sal > ANY (2000, 3000, 4000);

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7566       2975
      7698       2850
      7782       2450
      7788       3000
      7839       5000
      7902       3000
```

“All”: It is equivalent to **“AND”** condition. Hence in below example when salary > 2000 and 3000 and 4000 is considered

```
SELECT empno, sal
FROM   emp
WHERE  sal > ALL (2000, 3000, 4000);

     EMPNO        SAL
---------- ----------
      7839       5000
```

Sample data:

```
| empno |  ename |       job |  mgr |             hiredate |  sal | comm | deptno |
|-------|--------|-----------|------|----------------------|------|------|--------|
|  7369 |  smith |     clerk | 7902 | 1980-12-17T00:00:00Z |  800 | null |     20 |
|  7499 |  allen |  salesman | 7698 | 1981-02-20T00:00:00Z | 1600 |  300 |      0 |
|  7521 |   ward |  salesman | 7698 | 1981-02-22T00:00:00Z | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
|  7566 |  jones |   manager | 7839 | 1981-04-02T00:00:00Z | 2975 | null |     20 |
|  7654 | martin |  salesman | 7698 | 1981-09-28T00:00:00Z | 1250 | 1400 |     30 |
|  7698 |  blake |   manager | 7839 | 1981-05-01T00:00:00Z | 2850 | null |     30 |
|  7782 |  clark |   manager | 7839 | 1981-06-09T00:00:00Z | 2450 | null |     10 |
|  7788 |  scott |   analyst | 7566 | 1987-04-19T00:00:00Z | 3000 | null |     20 |
|  7839 |   king | president | null | 1981-11-17T00:00:00Z | 5000 | null |     10 |
|  7844 | turner |  salesman | 7698 | 1981-09-08T00:00:00Z | 1500 |    0 |     30 |
|  7876 |  adams |     clerk | 7788 | 1987-05-23T00:00:00Z | 1100 | null |     20 |
|  7900 |  james |     clerk | 7698 | 1981-12-03T00:00:00Z |  950 | null |     30 |
|  7902 |   ford |   analyst | 7566 | 1981-12-03T00:00:00Z | 3000 | null |     20 |
|  7934 | miller |     clerk | 7782 | 1982-01-23T00:00:00Z | 1300 | null |     10 |
```